# some times getting ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mailer, mailboxer

ActiveRecord::AssociationTypeMismatch in ConversationsController#create

Notification(#105166720) expected, got Message(#103122560)

I have used the Mailboxer gem for email system as internal users communication.

def create

```
recipient_emails = conversation_params(:recipients).split(',')
recipients = User.where(email: recipient_emails).all

conversation = current_user.
  send_message(recipients, *conversation_params(:body, :subject)).conversation

redirect_to request.referer.gsub("user=",""), notice: "Your message has been sent."
```

end

Sometimes I am getting the above error while composing new email. I couldn't find error where it has been raising..

I would be appreciate If any one share knowledge on this.

Comment: show your model codes

Comment: hey, no models in our app. its gem https://github.com/ging/mailboxer check once library there we can get migrations directly by rails g mailboxer:install

Comment: no models in your app ...........strang!!!! and got association error which got only for association mismatch

Comment: Yes, its strange error to me also because as we are using the ruby library only.. Have you seen that library? and thank your for your replying..

Comment: are you trying to monkey patch the Message Model ?. Check if you have any message.rb file in `app/models` folder of your application.

Comment: @Rajuakula did you find a fix for this issue? I know it's a year old, but I have the same kind of error with mailboxer.

Answer (score 1):

Same here and I've create a Github issue: https://github.com/mailboxer/mailboxer/issues/322